# Show/hide in PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php

I am stuck a one issue where in I need to display order history for my users and function is as follows.

Order history - Each order summary - (click on details) - details get visible.
The issue I am facing is when is put class on JavaScript I see all details tab getting showed on one click as I need it to be the only on tab should be visible when user clicks on details and that should be for that order itself not for his rest of the orders.

Below is my code for PHP

```php
<div class="detail-btn" id="detail_button">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">DETAILS</a>
</div>

<div class="detailShow" id="detailbtnshow"></div>

<div class="detail-btn" id="detail_button">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">DETAILS</a>
</div>

<div class="detailShow" id="detailbtnshow"></div>

<div class="detail-btn" id="detail_button">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">DETAILS</a>
</div>

<div class="detailShow" id="detailbtnshow"></div>

<div class="detail-btn" id="detail_button">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">DETAILS</a>
</div>

<div class="detailShow" id="detailbtnshow"></div>
```

JavaScript which I have used is below.

```js
 $("#detail_button").click(function(){
    $("#detailbtnshow").slideToggle();
 });
```

I've tried using class the only issue is my all detail `div`s get open on one click but I want them to open one user clicks on relevant detail button

Comment: That's because all your id's and classes are same you need to have unique id's to target those or you should target the items the other way by using names etc....!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to show only next div of clicked div:

```
$(".detail-btn").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".detailShow").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: change class name to detail-btn

Answer (score 0):

Try This Snippet Code...

```js
$(".detail-btn").click(function(){
     $('.detailShow').hide();
     $(this).next(".detailShow").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.detailShow{ display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="detail-btn" id="detail_button" >
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">DETAILS</a>
  </div>
    <div class="detailShow" id="detailbtnshow"> 
 aa
    </div>

    <div class="detail-btn" id="detail_button" >
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">DETAILS</a>
  </div>
    <div class="detailShow" id="detailbtnshow"> 
 bb
    </div>
 
    <div class="detail-btn" id="detail_button" >
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">DETAILS</a>
  </div>
    <div class="detailShow" id="detailbtnshow"> 
 cc
    </div>
 
    <div class="detail-btn" id="detail_button" >
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">DETAILS</a>
  </div>
    <div class="detailShow" id="detailbtnshow"> 
 dd
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer though just wanted to know if we can add any function to close previously opened div through the same js

Comment: do you want to show only one div at a time ?? @DeepakSingh

Comment: @DeepakSingh I've edited the answer and added a line in js function to hide the previously opened div... Enoy :)

Comment: And don't forgot to up vote and accept the answer which was helpful for you... ;)

Comment: this is not working properly I've added on my site too...  Check here

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/b0rh6k9L/100/)

Comment: look at your js code bro you are using `nextAll()` in this line `$(this).nextAll(".detailShow").toggle();` use only `next()` like this `$(this).next(".detailShow").slideToggle();`

Comment: `nextAll()` will toggle all the elements next to clicked element, nut `next()` will toggle only one element next to clicked element... @DeepakSingh

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PHP approach to do it but it's ugly to do something like this way :

```
<script>
<?php
// Assuming Items will be the array which will contain orders 
$count = count($items);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{ ?>
$(".detail-btn_<?php echo $i; ?>").click(function(){
$(".detailShow_<?php echo $i; ?>").slideToggle();
});
<?php } ?>
</script>

<?php
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{ ?>
<div class="detail-btn_<?php echo $i; ?>" id="detail_button">
<a href="javascript:void(0)">DETAILS</a></div>
<div class="detailShow_<?php echo $i; ?>" id="detailbtnshow"> 
</div>
});
<?php } ?>
```